# How to resolve 'Build failed: function.js does not exist; Error ID: 7485c5b6'

Tags: nodejs, chainlink

I'm trying to deploy a Chainlink external adapter to Google Cloud Function but running into the above error. I am using this template for the external adapter.
https://github.com/thodges-gh/CL-EA-NodeJS-Template

I've followed the exact steps as laid out in this tutorial:
https://youtu.be/N8a0590QD74?t=1340

I specify 'gcpservice' as the entry point but the deployment fails and I get the error message:
'Build failed: function.js does not exist; Error ID: 7485c5b6'

Been stuck here for a while. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this function in your index.js still?

```
// This is a wrapper to allow the function to work with
// GCP Functions
exports.gcpservice = (req, res) => {
  createRequest(req.body, (statusCode, data) => {
    res.status(statusCode).send(data)
  })
```

If you have that then you just need to put gcpservice as the entry point and it should work ok

Comment: Yes, I do have that function. I'm using the Chainlink EA template as given. I specify gcpservice as the cloud function entry point, but it always fails with the above error.

Answer (score 0):

I got the adapter to run on GCP cloud function by copying the contents of each file in the external adapter into the cloud functions inline editor when creating the function. I created one file after another in the inline editor and copied in content from the corresponding external adapter files. This is different from the method of uploading the external adapter zip file to create a cloud function, which refused to work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).